# invoke Clojure from Java : java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

Tags: java, clojure

Trying to use the approach described [here](http://clojurefun.wordpress.com/2012/12/24/invoking-clojure-code-from-java/) I eventually came to the following simplified , narrow-down code that still exhibits the exception:

```
import clojure.lang.RT;

public class FooMain {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        RT.var("clojure.core", "read-string").invoke("(+ 1 2)"); // line-6
    }
}
```

Which fails at runtime with the trace I append at the end of the post. I've tried that with either Clojure 1.4 or 1.5 Ivy deps:

```
<dependency org="org.clojure" name="clojure" rev="1.4.0"/>
```

or:

```
<dependency org="org.clojure" name="clojure" rev="1.5.1"/>
```

### trace

```
 run:
 [echo] ant.java.version=1.7
 [echo] running the app with classpath = /home/mperdikeas/esavo-reg/playground/calling-clojure-from-Java/lib-ivy/clojure-1.4.0-javadoc.jar:/home/mperdikeas/esavo-reg/playground/calling-clojure-from-Java/lib-ivy/clojure-1.4.0-sources.jar:/home/mperdikeas/esavo-reg/playground/calling-clojure-from-Java/lib-ivy/clojure-1.4.0.jar:/home/mperdikeas/esavo-reg/playground/calling-clojure-from-Java/dist/foo.jar
 [java] java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.execute(ExecuteJava.java:194)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.run(Java.java:771)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:221)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:135)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.execute(Java.java:108)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:398)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
 [java] Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 [java]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 [java]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)
 [java]     at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2056)
 [java]     at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:419)
 [java]     at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:400)
 [java]     at clojure.lang.RT.doInit(RT.java:436)
 [java]     at clojure.lang.RT.<clinit>(RT.java:318)
 [java]     at FooMain.main(FooMain.java:6)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.run(ExecuteJava.java:217)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.execute(ExecuteJava.java:152)
 [java]     ... 34 more
 [java] Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
 [java]     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:454)
 [java]     at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:582)
 [java]     at clojure.core$fn__6145.invoke(core.clj:6247)
 [java]     at clojure.core__init.load(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at clojure.core__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
 [java]     ... 48 more
 [java] Java Result: -1
```

Comment: Is it possible that line 9 is the next one following the code you posted? I just tried that code with 1.5.1 and I'm not getting a `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: @juan.facorro yeah I narrowed it down further, see updated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer thanks to [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17351585/274677).

Both:

- clojure-1.5.1.jar

  *and*
- clojure-1.5.1-sources.jar

include a `clojure/version.properties` file. However, the one in `clojure-1.5.1-sources.jar` doesn't contain a parsable version, but instead has the following contents:

```
version=${version}
```

Simply removing `clojure-1.5.1-sources.jar` from the CLASSPATH (or, in my case setting the `type="jar"` in the `<ivy:retrieve>` Ant task) fixes the issue.

Answer (score 3):

The exception you're seeing is thrown while the Clojure runtime is attempting to load the `clojure.core` namespace, before any of your code gets executed. Specifically, it appears that the exception is thrown while trying to parse a version number from the `clojure/version.properties` resource on the classpath.

- Ensure that this resource does in fact exist.
- Ensure that the resource is accessible from the classloader that you're using.

Comment: clojure/version.properties lives in clojure-1.4.0.jar which is on the classpath, should I by any chance need to go through the arcana of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13423048/why-does-clojure-use-the-context-classloader-by-default  ?

Comment: You might - it could be that Clojure isn't playing very nicely with whatever classloader Ant is using. My first thought would be to add `Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(RT.class.getClassLoader());` at the beginning of your method. Good luck - Clojure classloading issues are very difficult to track down in my experience.

Comment: You are right on the messed-up interplay between Clojure and Ant. Invoking it directly from the command line (not through Ant's `java` task) works fine and doesn't even need the `setContextClassLoader`. I can live with that.

Comment: I think I stumbled on the answer sometime later by accident. See  my answer below. It indeed has to do with `version.properties` but is not a Clojure / Ant classloader thing.